# PySpark - Add a composite key name to the Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, list-comprehension

Please bare with me if there are any mistakes as this is my first post.

This is the dataframe df: column 'a' is a string and rest are float.

I have added an image for the dataframe as somehow the formatting is getting messed up when I manually added the data.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV0H5.png)

On the given dataFrame df, I wanted to groupby column 'a' and find the min and max of each other column.I want to get the output as dictionary.So, I converted the resultant pyspark dataframe toJSON and using json.loads converted to Dictionary.

```
Code snippet:

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cols=['b','c']

req_cols=[F.struct(F.first('a').alias('a'),F.max(col).alias('max'),F.min(col).lias('min')).alias(col) for col in cols]

df_cache=df.groupby('a').agg(*req_cols).cache()

dict=json.loads(df_cache.toJSON.collect()[0])
```

My output:

```
{
  "b": {
      "max":
      "min":
       "a":'10'
       },
   "c": {
      "max":
      "min":
      "a":'10'
       },
}
```

Required output:

```
{
  "b_10": {
      "max":
      "min":
       "a":'10'
       },
   "c_10": {
      "max":
      "min":
      "a":'10'
       },
   "b_20": {
      "max":
      "min":
       "a":'20'
       },
   "c_20": {
      "max":
      "min":
      "a":'20'
       },
   "b_30": {
      "max":
      "min":
       "a":'30'
       },
   "c_30": {
      "max":
      "min":
      "a":'30'
       },
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HV8g.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pivot when grouping

```
df_cache = df.groupBy().pivot('a').agg(*req_cols).cache()
```

the column names will be different from your desired output so you need to change them if you want

Comment: Thanks a lot . I implemented the same in my code and it works as expected.